# Get values out of multi-select combobox

Tags: powerapps

I have a dropdown list bound to a User/Group type field of a SharePoint list. I can select multiple users and would like to collect their email address.
I expected that this would work. My delimiter is `;`, that is correct.

```
Concat(lsOwner.SelectedItems.DisplayName; ";")
```

The problem is that this returns only empty strings. I have 2 users selected, and the result is `;;`.
To check, if the values present, I mapped the result to a listbox and there I can see the 2 mail addresses.
Just to be curious, I tried to collect the addresses from the listbox like:

```
Concat(ListBox1.SelectedItems.Value ;"")
Concat(ListBox1.SelectedItems.Email ;"")
```

Both of them returned empty strings (even tough the email address were visible in the list), when I selected one or more.
Please, somebody tell me what do I do wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter of the [Concat function](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-concatenate) is the expression that will be applied to the records of the first parameter. What you want is likely the following expression:

```
Concat(
    lsOwner.SelectedItems;
    DisplayName;
    ";")
```

Comment: Need to be commas, though: `Concat(lsOwner.SelectedItems, DisplayName, ";");`

Comment: The original post uses `;` as the list / parameter separator, likely due to using a language where `,` is the decimal separator, which is why in the answer I followed their pattern. If this is not your case, then you're correct, a `,` needs to be used to separate the function arguments. See https://learn.microsoft.com/power-platform/power-fx/global#formula-separators-and-chaining-operator for more details.

Comment: Makes sense. If their language uses a comma as a decimal-separator, as in `1.111,11`, apparently they do use semi-colons in their code... In the U.S., we use the reverse, a `1,111.11` format, so apparently that's why we have to use a comma-separator in our code (except when stringing multiple commands together in `If` statements, where we do use a semi-colon there, ex. `If(ThisItem.ID = 1, *do this*; *and do this too*, *but do this only if the ID is NOT 1*)`. Interesting.